# Calculating vertex normals from surface normals

Tags: c++, math, directx, vertex, plane

I am trying to calculate vertex normals for terrain lighting calculation from surface normals(Triangles in a terrain). I know two ways of doing this but not sure which one is accurate.

Method 1: Add normalized surface normal of each surface that the vertex is in contact with and then normalize the resulting sum.

**Vertex Normal= Normalized(sum of (Normalized (Surface Normal))**

Method 2: Add un-normalized surface normal of each surface that the vertex is in contact with  and then averaging it then normalizing the result.

**Vertex Normal= Normalized(Average of Un-normalized Surface Normals)**

I know both methods dont yield the same result, So which method is the most accurate to use?

Comment: What kind of effect do you want? Do you want the appearance of smooth or hard lighting edges?

Comment: Smooth lighting edges but also wanted to know which method is accurate in mathematical sense.

Comment: Mathematically, surface normals are always unit magnitude, so the two approaches are identical.  In practical application, the difference completely depends on the calculation that caused the surface normal to be non-unit magnitude.

Comment: The difference is going to depend on a lot of things, but the main concern you have is how big the sum value gets. With Method 2, you don't have a bound so you could lose a lot of floating-point precision.

Comment: BTW, you may want to review the following papers: [Jin et al](http://www.tricity.wsu.edu/~bobl/personal/mypubs/2003_vertnorm_tvc.pdf), [Max](https://computing.llnl.gov/vis/images/pdf/max_jgt99.pdf), and [Wagner](http://www.emeyex.com/site/tuts/VertexNormals.pdf). I used these as reference when implementing [DirectXMesh](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324981)

Comment: @MooseBoys Surface Normals are not always of Unit magnitude,they can have varying magnitude. Refer: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html  In my case, i calculate normal of a triangle which is the cross product of two sides of the triangle and there were several cases wherein surface normal had a magnitude greater than 1.

Comment: @mooonimoon Be careful with your assumptions here - while a point on a surface certainly has an infinite number of *normal vectors*, the term *surface normal* in my experience simply refers to the outward direction, and a unit magnitude is assumed for the vector quantity.  Many representations of surface normals (e.g. 2-channel bump maps) rely on this assumption.

Comment: @MooseBoys Surface normal is just a vector perpendicular to a surface. What you are referring to is unit surface normal. Yes you are right that in many cases they normalize the surface normal for calculations.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn The sum value in my case is not very large (less than 100 for sure) and i felt Method 1 would have more losses due to floating-point precision as each surface normal is normalized(involves taking a root and division). Also, will look at the papers you suggested.